# Generating a random number (1-2) as a variable then getting python to do one of two things based on the variable generated

Tags: python, random

I am making a card game and with 2 players. I want to make a system where it randomly selects one of the players then that player will go first. Here is my code. I am programming in python.

A random number between one and two is determined to decide which player will pick the first card.

```
  print("Determining which player will go first...")

  first = print(random.randint(1,2))

if first == int(1) :
   print(player1 + " will go first.")

if first == int(2):
   print(player2 + " will go first.")
```

[code (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZZPF.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oops, wasn't clear about that, quite tired. I am trying to figure out how to make python recognise the number generated and then follow a path based on that. Sorry!

Comment: Please visit [need to know about asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `first = print(random.randint(1,2))`. `print` doesn't return anything. This should be 
`first = random.randint(1,2)`.
Also, `int(1)` is not needed, as `1` is already an integer. So `first == 1` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
first = random.randint(1,2)

print(str(first)) #if you want to print the number generated.

if first == 1: 
    print("player1 will go first.")
elif first == 2: 
    print("player2 will go first.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import randint


current_player = randint(1, 2)
print("player{} will go first.".format(current_player))
```

I would do like this